# Error in saving model

Tags: pyspark

I am using pipeline for doing feature engineering and then model train validation split for hyper parameter optimization. I want to persist my best model for later use. I am using the following code :

```
tvs = TrainValidationSplit(estimator=pipeline,
                          estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                          evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
                          trainRatio=0.8)



model = tvs.fit(train) # model is the model with combination of parameters that performed best
model.save('models/logisticregression_best_model')
```

I get the following error : AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute '_transfer_param_map_to_java'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it changing this code :

```
model.save('models/logisticregression_best_model')
```

to this code :

```
model.bestModel.write().overwrite().save('models/logisticregression_best_model')
```